# Making seperate columns from dictionary items in the same df in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, addition

I have a huge dataframe (9530232x19) of twitter data. The first column includes a dictionary. I want to make seperate columns from that dictionary items in the same df. Also I have a dictionary in 'entities' column which I want to make a similar seperation.
[image: sample data]
I want to add the metrics as four new columns such as 'rtcount', 'reply_count', 'like_count', and  'quote_count', and entities['htype'] as a new column on the right of my existing df, without creating any more dataframes because this big df uses almost all of my 16 GB RAM and crashes occasionally. I know using a for loop for this big df is not an efficient way but I couldn't figure out how to do it otherwise.
Any help is very much appreciated.

```
htypedf=[]
t=[]
for i in range(0,len(d)):
    if i%100==0:
        print(i)
    htype=[]
    hasht=[]
    t=d[i:i+1]
    metrics=pd.Series(t['public_metrics'][0]).to_frame().T
    try:
        htype=list(map(lambda x : x['type'], t['entities'][0]['annotations']))
    except:
        htype=('NaN')

    d.iloc[i] = pd.concat([t, metrics, pd.DataFrame({'htype': [htype]})],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your for loop, try this:

```
d = pd.concat([t.drop['public_metrics'], t['public_metrics'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

Similar concept could be applied for fetching the htype, but handling that will depend on how you want the data retained. If you *only* want htype from the entities column, you could likely give the following a shot:

```
d = pd.concat([t.drop['entities'], t['entities'].apply(pd.Series)['htype']], axis=1)
```

To retain the entities column in addition to the new htype column, you should be able to use the following code instead (simply removing the drop function):

```
d = pd.concat([t, t['entities'].apply(pd.Series)['htype']], axis=1)
```

Let me know how this works for you!

New codeblock:

```
def fetch_htype(row):
    entities_dict = row['entities']
    if np.isnan(entities_dict):
        return pd.Series(data = '', index = ['htype'])
    else:
        return pd.Series(data = entities_dict['htype'], index = ['htype'])

d = pd.concat([d, t.apply(fetch_htype)], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the first one gave an error, but I deleted t.drop['entities'] part and worked for public_metrics. The problem is with the second one now. some 'entities' are NaN, and it says "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable" beacuse of this. How can I ignore Nans in this line of code?

Comment: Try the first part again as follows. If it works, I will edit my response! ```d = pd.concat([t, t['public_metrics'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)```

Comment: It works perfectly! and very very fast. Thanks! Any chance on the second one?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry; I misunderstood! As for entities having NaNs and throwing errors, there are two options: 1) changing the function passed to apply to account for NaNs, or 2) dealing with NaNs before applying. 2 is likely easier, so I am editing my post to account for that. Try the new code in the bottom codeblock!

Comment: It doesn't work, made no modifications on the data. NaNs are still there. I tried this once before and the result was the same. Can not change that column.

Comment: Alright, I made a function to try to account for NaNs. Give the bottom code block another try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232249/discussion-between-ipek-deveci-kocakoc-and-jake-steele).